# Is there any benefit to feeding a Pokemon 10 golden razz berries?

Tags: pokemon-go

Will 10 raspberries increase the HP of the Pokemon drastically after each fight, just like feeding them to Pokemon with low HP?

Comment: A Golden Razz fully restores the Pokemon's motivation. Using it again would be a waste...

Comment: @Wondercricket why not make an answer out of this? Sounds good enough to me.

Answer (score 7):

A Golden Razzberry functions slightly different than the regular Razzberry. When using this berry, it fully restores the Pokémon's motivation in the gym. In a casual manner, feeding a Pokémon multiple Golden Razzberrys would be a waste.

However, contrary to my previous comment, a benefit to using multiple Golden Razzberries within a short period of time would be to defend a friendly gym. If you are close by, or have a defender yourself while at a distance, you could monitor the motivation levels and feed a Golden Razzberry when a Pokémon is about to be kicked out. Rinse, wash, repeat until the attacking team has given up.